# ORA-00927: Missing Equal Sign Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update, left-join

I'm getting a confusing **"ORA-00927: Missing Equal Sign Oracle SQL"** error when trying to run this simple UPDATE statement.

The idea comes from when I want to update two different fields on the join statement.

The first one the STATUS update. It already has done, but when I tried to update STATUS and T_ID in the same period in a single query, it came error just like that.

My SQL Code:

```
UPDATE RKAP_PROYEKSI R
SET STATUS = ( 
WITH RP AS
(
  SELECT
    RKAP_PROYEKSI.ID AS ID,
    RKAP_PROYEKSI.TAHUN AS TAHUN,
    RKAP_PROYEKSI.KODE_ANGGARAN AS KODE_ANGGARAN,
    RKAP_PROYEKSI.JENIS_BIAYA AS JENIS_BIAYA,
    RKAP_PROYEKSI.SUBTOTAL AS SUBTOTAL,
    RKAP_PROYEKSI.TOTAL AS TOTAL,
    RKAP_PROYEKSI.BELONGS_TO AS BELONGS_TO,
    RKAP_PROYEKSI.NOMOR AS NOMOR,
    RKAP_PROYEKSI.STATUS AS STATUS,
    0 AS ZERO_STATUS,
    "123TRX12" AS TICK_ID
  FROM WOS.RKAP_PROYEKSI
  LEFT JOIN WOS.RKAP_MASTER_KODE ON RKAP_MASTER_KODE.ID_KODE = RKAP_PROYEKSI.KODE_ANGGARAN
  LEFT JOIN WOS.RKAP_USER ON RKAP_USER.BIRO = RKAP_MASTER_KODE.BIRO
  WHERE TAHUN = '2018' AND RKAP_MASTER_KODE.BIRO = 'BSI')
  SELECT RP.ZERO_STATUS, RP.TICK_ID
  FROM RP
  WHERE RP.ID = R.ID
)
```

Any well thought to advise will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: how multple value assign into single column???

Comment: you need to use Merge - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update multiple columns using tuples:

```
UPDATE RKAP_PROYEKSI R
    SET (STATUS, T_ID) = ( 
            WITH RP AS (
                  SELECT P.ID AS ID,
                         P.TAHUN AS TAHUN,
                         P.KODE_ANGGARAN AS KODE_ANGGARAN,
                         P.JENIS_BIAYA AS JENIS_BIAYA,
                         P.SUBTOTAL AS SUBTOTAL,
                         P.TOTAL AS TOTAL,
                         P.BELONGS_TO AS BELONGS_TO,
                         P.NOMOR AS NOMOR,
                         P.STATUS AS STATUS,
                         0 AS ZERO_STATUS,
                         '123TRX12' AS TICK_ID
                   FROM WOS.RKAP_PROYEKSI P LEFT JOIN
                        WOS.RKAP_MASTER_KODE MK
                        ON MK.ID_KODE = P.KODE_ANGGARAN LEFT JOIN
                        WOS.RKAP_USER U
                        ON U.BIRO = MK.BIRO
                   WHERE P.TAHUN = '2018' AND 
                         MK.BIRO = 'BSI'
                  )
            SELECT RP.ZERO_STATUS, RP.TICK_ID
            FROM RP
            WHERE RP.ID = R.ID
           );
```

Fascinating.  I didn't realize that CTEs are not allowed in this context.  You need to phrase this as a subquery (which can have a CTE):

```
UPDATE RKAP_PROYEKSI R
    SET (STATUS, T_ID) = ( 
      SELECT RP.ZERO_STATUS, RP.TICK_ID
      FROM (WITH RP AS (
                  SELECT P.ID AS ID,
                         P.TAHUN AS TAHUN,
                         P.KODE_ANGGARAN AS KODE_ANGGARAN,
                         P.JENIS_BIAYA AS JENIS_BIAYA,
                         P.SUBTOTAL AS SUBTOTAL,
                         P.TOTAL AS TOTAL,
                         P.BELONGS_TO AS BELONGS_TO,
                         P.NOMOR AS NOMOR,
                         P.STATUS AS STATUS,
                         0 AS ZERO_STATUS,
                         '123TRX12' AS TICK_ID
                   FROM WOS.RKAP_PROYEKSI P LEFT JOIN
                        WOS.RKAP_MASTER_KODE MK
                        ON MK.ID_KODE = P.KODE_ANGGARAN LEFT JOIN
                        WOS.RKAP_USER U
                        ON U.BIRO = MK.BIRO
                   WHERE P.TAHUN = '2018' AND 
                         MK.BIRO = 'BSI'
                  )
             SELECT RP.*                
             FROM RP
            ) RP
      WHERE RP.ID = R.ID
     );
```

The CTE is, of course, just clutter.  You can simplify the query, but I assume you want a CTE.

Comment: It said, ORA-01767: UPDATE ... SET expression must be a subquery sir. @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @aldi . . . I learned something.  You can use CTEs in subqueries in the `FROM` clause but not in this context.

Comment: OMG, It works like a charm! I should learn more about CTE, thanks a lot sir @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 0):

you are selecting multiple column but updating single column

```
UPDATE RKAP_PROYEKSI R
SET STATUS = ( 
WITH RP AS
(
  SELECT
    RKAP_PROYEKSI.ID AS ID,
    RKAP_PROYEKSI.TAHUN AS TAHUN,
    RKAP_PROYEKSI.KODE_ANGGARAN AS KODE_ANGGARAN,
    RKAP_PROYEKSI.JENIS_BIAYA AS JENIS_BIAYA,
    RKAP_PROYEKSI.SUBTOTAL AS SUBTOTAL,
    RKAP_PROYEKSI.TOTAL AS TOTAL,
    RKAP_PROYEKSI.BELONGS_TO AS BELONGS_TO,
    RKAP_PROYEKSI.NOMOR AS NOMOR,
    RKAP_PROYEKSI.STATUS AS STATUS,
    0 AS ZERO_STATUS,
    "123TRX12" AS TICK_ID
  FROM WOS.RKAP_PROYEKSI
  LEFT JOIN WOS.RKAP_MASTER_KODE ON RKAP_MASTER_KODE.ID_KODE = RKAP_PROYEKSI.KODE_ANGGARAN
  LEFT JOIN WOS.RKAP_USER ON RKAP_USER.BIRO = RKAP_MASTER_KODE.BIRO
  WHERE TAHUN = '2018' AND RKAP_MASTER_KODE.BIRO = 'BSI')
  SELECT min(RP.ZERO_STATUS)
  FROM RP
  WHERE RP.ID = R.ID
)
```